# One Django app in a separate python package

Tags: django

Django==3.2.5

Have a look at this picture:

[image]

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'clients',
    'general',
    'images',
    'themes',
    'omnibus',
    'staticassets',
    'categories',
    'tags',
    'articles',
]
```

When I run this, I get:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'articles'
```

It is predictable as Django doesn't know where to find the app.

Then I tried like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'dependencies.articles',
]
```

No success.

Here 'articles' is just an ordinary Django app like categories or clients. But I'd like to move it to 'depencencies' package. Why? I'd like to organize the code structure like this for as personal preferences. How can I cope with this problem, assuming it is technically possible?

Comment: "Have a look at this picture" - can you explain what the relevance of the image is? What are readers looking at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cut the articles directory back to the main block project directory

as of now :

blog_project
|
|---dependencies
|
----- articles

needs to be :

blog_project
|
|---articles

get rid of the dependencie directory it no use

Comment: But I"d like to have dependencies package.

Comment: I think you are mistaking, you are trying to put an app directory into a random folder, django doesn't allow it

Comment: @trts are you good now ?